# why do we need the pure <?> in Java?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

why do we need the pure `<?>` in Java?
Does anything passed can only be used as Object ? So it's the same useful as any class casted to Object (only 9 methods could be available)

Thanks

---

I mean, if you have List< ? > list, you can only use items as Object. This means list.get(0) gives you Object and nothing more. Yes, also I can store to there anything, but is it useful for you? It's like you have a good an expensive thing and put it to a garbage bin. The only you can get from a trash bin is trash. As well you can put any good object of any class to List but get only Object from there with only 9 methods.

Comment: Might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super

Comment: `List<?>`  is not the same as `List<Object>`. It's the same as `List<? extends Object>`

Comment: sure, i just wrote "can only be used as Object " and "it's the same useful as any class casted to Object". So any class could be casted to Object as well as the any class can be posted to <?>

Comment: What do you mean by "anything passed can only be used as Object"? Passed (used?) how/where? Could you post some example which will clarify your question? Possibly while writing such example you will also find answer to your queston...

Comment: A `List<Object>` allows you to `add` **anything** to the `List` as it contains objects. A `List<?>` does **not** allow you to `add` anything to the `List` as it contains some specific unknown type. The to are very, very different.

Comment: I mean, if you have List<?> list, you can only use items as Object. This means list.get(0) gives you Object and nothing more. Yes, also I can store to there anything, but is it useful for you? It's like you have a good an expensive thing and put it to a garbage bin. The only you can get from a trash bin is trash. As well you can put any good object of any class to List<?> but get only Object from there with only 9 methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two scenarios where an unbounded wildcard is a useful approach:

- If you are writing a method that can be implemented using functionality provided in the `Object` class.
- When the code is using methods in the generic class that don't depend on the type parameter.
  For example, `List.size`, or `List.clear`. In fact, `Class<?>` is so often used because most of the methods in `Class<T>` don't depend on `T`.

For example, see [`Collections.swap`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java#l538) method:

```
public static void swap(List<?> list, int i, int j) {
    final List l = list;
    l.set(i, l.set(j, l.get(i)));
}
```

Knowing the type does not aid in swapping two elements within a `List`,  so an unbounded wildcard is used. You pass in a `List` - any `List` - and the method swaps the indexed elements. There is no type parameter to worry about.

For more information, see: [Unbounded Wildcards.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html)

Comment: Your `swap` example is a bit of a dirty hack - it uses a rawtype to fix the wildcard problem. `public static <E> void swap(List<E> list, int i, int j)` would be a better option.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best answer is because sometimes you literally do not know what type a class is parameterized with.  As Michael pointed out `List<?>` is not the same as `List<Object>`.  So `?` provides different semantics, which are useful in ensuring program correctness.

Consider two lists.  One list is `List<String>` and the other is `List<Integer>`.  Both of those are `Object`s, but we still don't want to get them mixed up.  We don't want to put a `String` in the `Integer` list or vice-versa.  So if you have a type declared as `List<?>`, you cannot safely put any type in that list.  The `?` could be `String` or `Integer`, but you don't know what it is, and you don't want to mix them up, so you can't put either in.

OTOH, `List<Object>` is just a list of objects, and since you declared it to hold any objects, you can safely put both `String` and `Integer` in the list.  You said you didn't care what went into the list by declaring it of type `Object`, so any type is fine.  In any meaningful way I can think of, `List<Object>` is equivalent to a raw type.  It's a list that you manage yourself, without help from the compiler.